# remove file path in terminal and just display a folder

Tags: file, path, terminal, toggle, iterm

So to get started with my work I usually have to cd into a specific folder in iterm2. 
Sorta looks like this [johnson@david-MacBook-Pro /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/demoapp] 16:41:32 $

As you can see that takes up a ton of room in the damn window. How do I remove the name of the path and just have it so its like this 
demoapp ->

I've seen this in video tutorials where the only thing on the screen is the name of the folder or directory the person is in without all the extra info. 
Obviously this a Mac specific question. Is it possible to toggle between showing full path and just specific path for quick reference?

thanks!

Comment: Please ask a single question.

Answer (score 0):

When one uses a Terminal (in Linux or Mac) initiated as root, only the actual directory is shown. In my case (using Linux Mint), if I start a normal Terminal, and use the command su to login as root, the complete path changes to the actual directory.

Try this:
a) write su on the Terminal
b) enter...
c) it asks for the root password, write it and press enter again.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a ton. Although your suggestion work, initially I was not able to 'login as root'. I would type in su and hit enter and no matter how many times i entered my password I'd get "sorry". 

For everyone's benefit who might be dealing with this problem here is how to enable root login on a mac.
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528